# How do I make a list of imported classes in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, import, module

```
from module import a, b, c
foo(a)
foo(b)
foo(c)
```

Is there a way to avoid having to call `foo(x)`for each imported object?

Some context: a, b, c are webpage classes and foo is a route() function that creates a route for each webpage.

Update: There will be a growing list of imported classes in the main module as the application grows. I mentioned a, b, and c simply as an example. I am looking for something like `import a, b, c to classes_list` and then I can iterate over the `classes_list` instead of calling foo on each of the imported classes.

Comment: The same way you would iterate over anything else: with either a comprehension or a loop.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel that's the easy part. The hard part is how to make the iterable.

Comment: ...You have variables `a`, `b` and `c`, and the hard part is how to make a list that contains them? Or perhaps you think there is something special just because you defined them using an `import`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the difficulty is to generate the list of imported objects dynamically. There are many objects being imported, not only three.

Comment: ... But explicitly naming them all on the `import` line was fine? There's only a point to this if you're also going to do the import dynamically, in which case that would seem to be the real question.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am fine with explicitly naming them. I am not fine with explicitly calling foo for each of them.

Comment: Do you have control over the imported module? You could generate the pages into a sequence and map through it instead. Also, please specify whether you mean class definitions or instantiated objects with variable names a, b and c. It's technically possible to call a function on a Class definition, but I don't know why you'd want to do that here.

Comment: @RyanDeschamps I meant classes, not object instances. I do have control over the imported module. Please note that each class (`a, b, c`, etc.) is in a separate module (e.g. `a.py, b.py`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have no other imports, you could iterate over globals().items() to gather all the classes. You may need to filter further if there are additional classes in your overall imports.

```
import inspect
from pandas import DataFrame, Grouper, ExcelFile

imps = globals().items()
filtered_imps = [x[1] for x in imps if inspect.isclass(x[1])]
print(filtered_imps)
```

Produces:

```
[<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, <class 'pandas.core.groupby.grouper.Grouper'>, <class 'pandas.io.excel._base.ExcelFile'>]
```

Then you can `foo()` over the list as necessary in a loop or as part of the comprehension, perhaps using a `try ... except` to deal with exceptions on the way.

Comment: It might be safer to use try .. except in a for loop instead of running the function in the list.

Answer (score 1):

`from module import a, b, c` is already basically just shorthand for

```
import module


for x in ['a', 'c', 'c']:
    globals()[x] = getattr(module, x)
```

You can insert your own wrapper around the value injected into the global namespace.

```
import module

for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    globals()[x] = foo(getattr(module, x))
    # foo(getattr(module, x))  # If you don't actually need the global name
```

For multiple modules, you can define a dict mapping module names to class names and use `importlib.import_module`, rather than an `import` statement, to do the actual import.

```
from importlib import import_module

classes = {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}

for m, c in classes.items():
    globals()[c] = getattr(import_module(m), c)
```

Comment: Thank you! While that would be a solution, I am choosing Ryan Deschamps' answer as the correct answer because I think it's better to import all classes first with `import `statements as opposed to writing them as strings in a list. One reason for that is the IDE letting you know if you did a typo during the imports.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the imports to a list then use a for loop:

```
import_list =  [a,b,c]

for x in import_list:
   foo(x)
```

Comment: Yeah, but how did a, b, and c end up so nicely on your list?

Comment: If the code had instead said `a = 1`, `b = 2`, `c = 3`, and then `import_list = [a, b, c]`, would that also be confusing?

Comment: How did they end up so nicely in your imports?

Comment: @Bjorn, sorry, I think my question was not that clear. The real question is how to obtain that list of classes without having to type it manually.

Comment: @multigoodverse I think we would need more information about your code to answer that