# list all the imports from the given python code as a string

Tags: python, regex

List all the imports from the given python code

Example:

```
**Input**:
import string
**Output**: ['string']
```

Example2:

**NOTE:If a package is imported with alias name i.e. "as" it should only print alias name not the package name**

```
    **Input:**
    from string import digit, ascii_lowercase
    from datetime import datetime as dt, date as d, time as t
    # This is a comment
    def met_02():
        pass
    print('print this')
    **output**: ['digit', 'ascii_lowercase', 'dt', 'd', 't']
```

I tried this following code but it prints only imports but it should print imports after alias ("as") if exists else print package after alias as mentioned in example 2

```
def list_imports(lines):
    imports = []
    for file in lines:
            result = re.findall(r"(?<!from)import (\w+)[\n.]|from\s+(\w+)\s+import", lines)
            for imp in result:
                for i in imp:
                    if len(i):
                        if i not in imports:
                            imports.append(i)

    return (imports)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a list of imported classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080864/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-imported-classes-in-python)

Comment: python code is passed as a string

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572582/return-a-list-of-imported-python-modules-used-in-a-script it seems as this has been asked a lot before

Comment: Import lines can also start with "from", e.g., `from math import sqrt`.

Comment: What do you need that list for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re

def list_imports(lines):
    result = []
    
    # visit lines
    for line in lines:
        # get words after import definition
        for modules in re.compile('import (.*)$').findall(line):
            # split with comma
            for module in modules.split(','):
                # if module has 'as' keyword
                if ' as ' in module:
                    # get word after 'as' keyword
                    result.extend(re.compile('as\s+(\w+)').findall(module))
                else:
                    # add found module
                    result.append(module.strip())
    return result

lines = "from string import digit, ascii_lowercase\nfrom datetime import datetime as dt, date as d, time as t".split('\n')

print(list_imports(lines))
```

Comment: this returns nothing

Comment: the code is working, I added example line code, could you try again?